# what will be the code for 54321 4321 321 21

Tags: c

Hi everyone i need a C program to print:

```
54321
 4321
  321
   21
    1
```

I could get the numbers but am failing to understand how to space it like the above. Hope I could get some help. Thanks!

```
int n, j;
for (n = 5; n >= 1; n--) {
     for (j = n; j >= 1; j-- ) {
          printf("%d", j);
     }
     printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Don't spam tags. Only one of the tags you assigned are actually relevant to this post.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a practical programming problem. The problem is intended to make the aspiring programmer think. It is not intended to ask around for a solution.

Comment: Add a `for` loop to print the required number of spaces before the loop that prints the numbers. It's simple maths/logic to work out how many spaces need to be printed for each line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print a number of spaces before the digits. That number depends on `n`. No need to have a loop since `Printf` format string allows you to put the width of a field in the argument list by using a `*` like this:

```
int n, j;
for (n = 5; n >= 1; n--) {
    printf("%*s", n - 5, "");
    for (j = n; j >= 1; j--)
        printf("%d", j);
    printf("\n");
}
```